# generating a multi dict with random numbers

Tags: python-2.7, gurobi

I have a data structure defined as follow :

```
reqList[i] = [multidict({
    1: ['type1', randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5)],
    2: ['type2', randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5)],
    3: ['type3', randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5)],
    4: ['type4', randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5)]
}),
    multidict({
        (1, 2): randint(500, 1000),
        (2, 3): randint(500, 1000),
        (3, 4): randint(500, 1000)
    })]
```

I want to make the creation of this data structure automatic in a for loop for example. I did this:

```
nodes = {}
for j in range(1, randint(2, 5)):
    nodes[j] = ['type%d' % j, randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5)]

edges = {}
for kk in range(1, len(nodes)):
    edges[(kk, kk + 1)] = randint(500, 1000)

print "EDGES", edges
reqList[i] = [multidict(nodes),
              multidict(edges)]

del (nodes, edges)
```

when I look into the outputed edges the order of the keys is not kept ! For example I am getting this:

```
EDGES {(1, 2): 583, (3, 4): 504, (2, 3): 993}
```

I want it to be :

```
EDGES {(1, 2): 583, (2, 3): 993, (3, 4): 504}
```

Does the way I am coding it is correct ? if not, could you suggest a better way knowing that I need to get the same result as in the first example?

Comment: Which version of Python? Dictionaries are unordered (below 3.6), if you want an ordered dictionary look into the `collection` module

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and the multidict data structure provided by Gurobi

Comment: just to confirm you want to keep the order in the dictionary as you are creating them ?

Comment: yes @MooingRawr and I want to only use multidict.

Comment: @MooingRawr I checked the type of    1: ['type1', randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5)],
 it says that it is a tuplelist ! I need to come up with the same outcome but I do not know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary in 2.7 is unordered and you can not keep the order of insert, unless you manually keep a reference on what key got inserted and when in a separate list. The module `collections` contains a class called `OrderedDict` that acts like a dictionary but keeps the inserts in ordered, which is what you could use (it also uses a list to keep track of the keys insert but uses a double link list to speed up deletion of keys).

There's no other way other than these two method.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

nodes = {}
for j in range(1, randint(2, 5)):
    nodes[j] = ['type%d' % j, randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5), randint(1, 5)]

edges = OrderedDict()
for kk in range(1, len(nodes)):
    edges[(kk, kk + 1)] = randint(500, 1000)

print "EDGES", edges # EDGES OrderedDict([((1, 2), 898), ((2, 3), 814)])

print edges[(1,2)] # still yields the correct number
```

You can read more about [`OrderedDict` here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)

Comment: Thanks for this solution :). The thing is that I need to use multidict that is provided by gurobi API as all my code depends on it.

Comment: I'm not sure what gurobi's API multidict does so it's hard for me to give you an answer you want, maybe wait for someone with Gurobi knowledge to come along. Also not sure why it would care about the order of the dictionary, kinda defeats the purpose of a dictionary.